# Oracle 11g - Spool file - enforcing not quoted columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am trying to spool large datasets (200k+ row) to csv format and need the columns not to be quoted. This is possible via the export settings of the SQL Developer GUI, but I am trying to do this via a SQL script.  The resulting csv file is then read by another application.  To demonstrate this I run the below script.

```
set ECHO      off
set FEEDBACK  off
set LINESIZE  60
set RECSEP    off
set TRIMSPOOL on
set VERIFY    off
set PAGESIZE  0
set SQLFORMAT csv
spool y:\aa.csv
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;
spool off
```

This gives the ouput

```
"PRODUCT","VERSION","STATUS"
"NLSRTL ","11.2.0.4.0","Production"
"Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition ","11.2.0.4.0","64bit Production"
"PL/SQL ","11.2.0.4.0","Production"
"TNS for Linux: ","11.2.0.4.0","Production"
```

I need the output as below (NO QUOTED STRINGS)

```
PRODUCT,VERSION,STATUS
NLSRTL ,11.2.0.4.0,Production
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition ,11.2.0.4.0,64bit Production
PL/SQL ,11.2.0.4.0,Production
TNS for Linux: ,11.2.0.4.0,Production
```

I would rather not post-process the file (powershell, perl, etc) after generation and before loading as it just adds unnecessary steps to a process.

How can I do a spool file where I can specify the left and right enclosures even setting them to NULL.

Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

`set SQLFORMAT` is a SQLcl option.

I am not aware of any option in SQLcl that removes the quotes.

`SQL*Plus` starting with version 12.2 supports csv output with the `SET MARKUP` option:

```
SQL> set markup csv on
SQL> SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;

"PRODUCT","VERSION","VERSION_FULL","STATUS"
"Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition ","19.0.0.0.0","19.3.0.0.0","Production"
```

You can simply disable quotes if needed:

```
SQL> set markup csv on quote off
SQL> SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;

PRODUCT,VERSION,VERSION_FULL,STATUS
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition ,19.0.0.0.0,19.3.0.0.0,Production
```

Setting a custom delimiter:

```
SQL> set markup csv on delimiter | quote off
SQL> SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;

PRODUCT|VERSION|VERSION_FULL|STATUS
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition |19.0.0.0.0|19.3.0.0.0|Production
```

Comment: OP's version is 11.  That's a question in itself...

Comment: @kevinsky OP can download and install a 12.2 client with SQL*Plus, just as SQLcl was downloaded and installed. The version of the database is irrelevant, as long as the client is compatible with it.